# Issue with adding a new line using PhpWord\TemplateProcessor

Tags: php

I am trying to fill a word template with text retrieved from an html file. The issue is that new lines are not created in the new created docx file. I get something like:

```
<br> - Ingredienti : <br>   - 2 Melanzane (circa 1 kg)<br>   - 3 spicchi d'aglio<br>   - 30 ml di succo di limone<br>
```

As you can see `<br>` is not translated to new line. Here is the code I am using:

```
use PhpOffice\PhpWord\TemplateProcessor;

....
function fillTemplate($templatePath, $outputPath, $context) {
    try {
        // Load the template
        $templateProcessor = new TemplateProcessor($templatePath);
        PhpOffice\PhpWord\Settings::setOutputEscapingEnabled(true);
        // Replace placeholders with provided content
        foreach ($context as $placeholder => $content) {
            // Replace the placeholder
            $templateProcessor->setValue($placeholder, $content);
        }
        // Save the generated document
        $templateProcessor->saveAs($outputPath);

        // Output debug information
        echo "Template processed successfully. Output saved to: $outputPath\n";
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        // Handle errors
        echo "Error processing template: " . $e->getMessage() . "\n";
    }
}
```

Any help/advice is appreciated

The resulted output docx file shows "
" instead of creating the new line in the word document.

Comment: have you tried replacing the `<br>` with a `\n` . `$content = str_replace('<br>', "\n", $content);`

Comment: I tried it as well. no new line is produced in the output docx file.